# Reanimated 2 animation entering/exiting withCallback error

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

If I use withCallback function on animation enter/exit or even when using the keyframe to create custom animation I get an error.
Am I doing something wrong, or maybe missing something?

"react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",

```js
<Animated.View
   entering={SlideInLeft.duration(animationDuration)}
   exiting={SlideOutRight.duration(animationDuration).withCallback(()=>{})}
>
   <View />
</Animated.View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed with

```js
const slideInLeft = SlideInLeft.withCallback((finished: boolean) => {
    'worklet';
    if (finished) {
     yourFoo(
    }
});

<Animated.View entering={slideInLeft} >
   ...
</Animated.View>
```